# Querying a related object created in a trigger after DML - Possible?

Tags: trigger, soql, before-trigger, triggercontext

Does a trigger execution happen on a separate thread?
Here is what I am trying to do.

```
public void static methodA() {
  //Do something
  //Create recordA of type objectA
  insert recordA;
  //trigger for objectA creates a recordB of type objectB
  //query objectB using an SOQL (filtering based on a field other than Salesforce Id) - POSSIBLE?? WOULD I GET A VALID RECORD?
}

trigger myTrigger on ObjectA {
  if((trigger.isInsert || trigger.isUpdate) && Trigger.isBefore) {
    //Do some more things
    //Create recordB of type objectB
    insert recordB;
  }
}
```

Would I get a valid record returned in the query on last line of methodA?
If No, what would be an alternative to fetching recordB?

Answer (score 0):

> Does a trigger execution happen on a separate thread?

No. All synchronous Apex is executed in a single thread for each transaction. Note that threads are rarely a useful framework for describing Salesforce execution contexts because you have no control over threading; rather it's usually more helpful to think in terms of transactions and synchronous versus asynchronous Apex.

In the scenario you describe, you would be able to query the created Object B record following the execution of `insert` DML on Object A.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Salesforce implements transaction-level database isolation. This means that two records inserted in two different transactions wouldn't be able to "see" each other until the transaction completes, but within one transaction (including all cascading triggers, etc), you can query those results in an after DML trigger or later. If this were not possible, [@testSetup](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_testsetup.htm) methods would literally be useless, as you'd have no way to get access to those records in your [@isTest](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_isTest.htm) unit tests.